# Redirect User to sub domain based on IP

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, http-redirect, response.redirect

I am trying to redirect the user to sub domain based on his IP address location. I have a page load observer which runs a function on each request and it gets the user Location and when I try to redirect to another domain it gives me "Too many redirects" error and I can't figure out a way to solve this issue.

Currently my code looks like as follows

```
string CountryName = "";
var Country = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["Country"];
Country.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip) && ip != null && ip != "127.0.0.1")
{
    using (var client = new WebServiceClient(xxxxx, "xxxxxxxx"))
    {
        var IpCountry = client.Country(ip);
        CountryName = IpCountry.Country.Name;
    }
    switch (CountryName)
    {
        case "Denmark":
            if (Country.Value != CountryName)
            {
                Country.Value = CountryName;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            break;
        case "United Kingdom":
            if (Country.Value != CountryName)
            {
                Country.Value = CountryName;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/en");
            }
            break;
        case "Germany":
            if (Country.Value != CountryName)
            {
                Country.Value = CountryName;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/de");
            }
            break;
        case "Sweden":
            if (Country.Value != CountryName)
            {
                Country.Value = CountryName;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/se");
            }
            break;
        case "Norway":
            if (Country.Value != CountryName)
            {
                Country.Value = CountryName;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/no");
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (Country.Value != CountryName)
            {
                Country.Value = CountryName;
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            }
            break;
    }
}
else if (loadedArgs.pageview.Area.ID != 2)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/choose-country");
}
```

Further more I also would like to know what could be other possible ways to handle this scenario in more better way so this code don't run on every page load once the cookies are set. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean when you uncomment redirect to google you are getting error to many redirects?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat No, When i comment-out all the redirects it works fine other wise it give me error Too many redirects. which though make sense as this code runs on page load and after redirecting it runs the code again and it gets into endless loop. So I want to figure out how to prevent it?

Comment: Where are you actually setting cookie with country name?

Comment: @Evk cookies are set in Country variable and after getting CountryName i am storing the value like this Country.Value = CountryName;

Comment: Might be cleaner solution to use a custom http handler to handle this for you.

Comment: Create a generic redirection page that accepts "folder" argument. Then on this one pass the folder to it. I think that is better.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have access to your code, but, if I am reading your code right the fix for the redirect issue is to check for the cookies existence before any creation/ redirection logic. I made some changes, please give this a try and let me know of any issues.

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
var cookieName = "Country";
var ip = context.Request.UserHostAddress;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip) && ip != "127.0.0.1")
{
    //If the cookie is present (means cookie is set already) then return
    if (context.Request.Cookies[cookieName] != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    string countryName;

    using (var client = new WebServiceClient(xxxxx, "xxxxxxxx"))
    {
        var ipCountry = client.Country(ip);
        countryName = ipCountry.Country.Name;
    }

    context.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(cookieName)
    {
        Value = countryName,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)
    });

    switch (countryName)
    {
        case "Denmark":
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            break;
        case "United Kingdom":
            context.Response.Redirect("/en");
            break;
        case "Germany":
            context.Response.Redirect("/de");
            break;
        case "Sweden":
            context.Response.Redirect("/se");
            break;
        case "Norway":
            context.Response.Redirect("/no");
            break;
        default:
            //context.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            break;
    }
}
else if (loadedArgs.pageview.Area.ID != 2)
{
    context.Response.Redirect("/choose-country");
}
```

Thank you,
Soma.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to get the client IP address. i.e., the IP address of the machine which requested a page in your website.

```
String UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserIP))
{
    UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Below is the format we need to use for the API URL.

```
freegeoip.net/{format}/{IP_or_hostname}
```

format –> is the response output format. It could be CSV or XML or JSON.

For example, if we would like to get the response in JSON format then we could use the API URL as 'http://freegeoip.net/json/clientIPAddress_here'

```
string url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" + UserIP.ToString();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string jsonstring = client.DownloadString(url);
```

To get the sample response format, run this http://freegeoip.net/json/XX.XX.XX.XX (replace XX.XX.XX.XX with the required ip address) URL directly in the browser. You will see the below response format.

```
{
"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
"country_code":"",
"country_name":"",
"region_code":"",
"region_name":"",
"city":"",
"zip_code":"",
"time_zone":"",
"latitude":0,
"longitude":0,
"metro_code":0
}
```

Use the below code to convert the response to JSON object and then read the values of JSON object and save to a session variable or some other variable.

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LocId"] = dynObj.country_code;
```

You can also detect the country using the [Location](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) header too 
On `HttpWebRequest` you can set `AllowAutoRedirect` to false to handle the redirect yourself.

```
// don't allow redirects, they are allowed by default so we're going to override
myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

// send the request
HttpWebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();

// check the header for a Location value
if( response.Headers["Location"] == null )
{
  // null means no redirect
}
else
{
  // anything non null means we got a redirect
}
```

**Solving the "Too many redirects" issue:**
Redirect loop is like a situation wherein  > **"A points to B and B points back to A"**
. Such a redirection will keep browser in an infinite loop and the webpage will never be displayed. In old times, such redirect or infinite loops used to result in a hung browser.Thankfully, modern browsers are able to detect such redirect loops and they break the cycle by displaying an error message: “Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): there were too many redirects”.

This problem may be caused either at the client end or the server end. If there is no redirection loop on the server side, the problem is likely to be solved just by deleting cookies from the browser.

**So I suggest please check your routeconfig.cs for such route Or similar redirect operation that points back to itself after deleting the  cookies from the browser**

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it doesn't solve my problem. My issue is with "Too many redirects" error as I have this code on page load observer which runs on every call to the page so after redirect the code runs again and it gets into endless loop so my basic question is that how to prevent it getting into endless loop?

Comment: @UmarKhan I've updated my answer please check the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the logic that does not identify if the request is before or after redirecting. The sequence seems to be

```
The code executes once when a URL xyz.com
The redirect to xyz.com/en happens
Again the code executes and tries to redirect to xyz.com/en/en
```

This can be confirmed with some more debugging.

I suggest your code should execute and redirect if the URL being requested doesn't end with "en" or "de" (the list can be maintained in the application)

You might need to change the way you handle your default country too, because if the logic is no country indicates default country, then what I mentioned above will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net MVC, I have a class that handles invalid IP addresses and re-directs them based on the IP address. I use the following code:

```
protected override async void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            var ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            if (await IpAddressValid(ipAddress)) return;
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
            var address = urlHelper.Action("InvalidIpRange", "Account");
            context.Result = new RedirectResult(address ?? "www.google.com");
        }

        private async Task<bool> IpAddressValid(string ipAddress)
        {
            if (ipAddress == "::1")
                return true;
            var longIp = Ip2Int(ipAddress);
            var addr = await GeoIPCountry.ReturnGeoIpCountries(longIp, longIp); //dbContext.GeoIPCountries.Where(x => x.Start >= longIp && x.End <= longIp);
            return addr.All(g => g.CountryCode == "US");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts IP Address to Long Stack Space.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ipAddress"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int Ip2Int(string ipAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                var addr = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
                uint ip =
                    (uint) IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((int) BitConverter.ToUInt32(addr.GetAddressBytes(), 0));
                return (int)ip;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

At the top of each controller that requires it, all you have to do is add  the [IpAddressAuthorize] flag and it will handle everything. This happens before any other action so if you should be able to modify it pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information on the 'observer that runs on every request', but if it really does run on every request, it will simply run again when you redirect the user after checking their country.

To debug this, simply place breakpoints wherever you call a redirect, and check which one gets repeatedly called.

For example, let's say that the user is from Denmark, in which case you

```
context.Response.Redirect("/");
```

But this will cause your 'observer' to run again and redirect again! So you need to check if the redirection already occurred by placing another cookie, or by checking whether the requested page is already a language-specific page and therefore there is no need to redirect again.